# Validating emails and applying length check

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a pattern that validates domain specific email addresses by ensuring they are in the format `email@domain.be` and have a total *length of between 12-41* characters.

I've had a look at some documentation and previous questions and I've come up with this. All test data returns as `false` however. How would you properly validate an email and apply a length range? Also, does the length range apply to the first [] or the entire address?

```
^([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@domain.be).{12,41}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the format check a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?=)`) so it doesn't consume characters and let the length do the actual matching:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@domain.be).{12,41}$
```